# visual basic 6 Class Image

Tags: class, vb6

I get error when I run my program.  I want to change the image to another image, but the image won't change.  Please help me to find out.

This is my code:

```
Public Image1Color As String
Public Image1 As Image

Public Sub CheckIn()
If Image1Color = "Green" Then
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("Color\red1.jpg")
    Image1Color = "Red"
Else
    MsgBox ("This table is already occupied!")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: At least specify the exact error you're getting. My best guess: your path is incorrect.

Comment: @RobIII when I run the program, there is error message appear...the message said Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set

Comment: Use the debugger or make sure you're not using "On error resume next" somewhere. Other that that: we're not clearvoyant. We need an exact error message to be able to help you out.

Comment: @RobIII anw, which path do you mean??
I'm a newbie in this program...

Comment: You provided 10 lines of code, one containing a path. Guess which I meant? The "Color\red1.jpg" ofcourse. Did you check the path is correct?

Comment: @RobIII the error at this line....Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("Color\red1.jpg")
Anyway, the path is correct since it's directory is in the same folder of the class module

Comment: **WHAT** is the error you're getting? "File not found"? "Moon is not in correct position today"? Again: My buest guess is the file is not found, maybe a typo in the path or filename. Also make sure the application is looking in the correct "base" directory (use [ChDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bws05bz(v=vs.80).aspx))

Comment: The error just contains "Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set"

Comment: Well, that explains a lot. You need to at least NEW (e.g. instantiate) an Image object. You can use the new keyword, creatobject etc. You'd probably want to do this in [Class_Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fxtxxwa(v=vs.80).aspx) (again, based on best guess...)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Set Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("Color\red1.jpg")
```

(Note the `Set`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stdpicture`

```
Dim pic As New StdPicture
Set pic = LoadPicture("")
Set Me.Picture = pic
```

in your code like:

```
Public Image1Color As String
Public Image1 As New StdPicture



Public Sub CheckIn()
If Image1Color = "Green" Then
   Set Image1 = LoadPicture("Color\red1.jpg")
    Image1Color = "Red"
Else
    MsgBox ("This table is already occupied!")
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize `Image1Color = "Green"` somewhere in your code.

If you don't initialize Image1Color then it will be an empty string and always go to the `Else` part of your statement

[EDIT]

I just read your comment about the error message.

It's easier to add an Image control to your form, and use that Image control, instead of declaring it in code.